# Перемещение кнопки по форме мышью в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как можно реализовать перемещение кнопки мышью по форме?
Ранее я это делал в WinForm вот так:

```
bool iMove = false;
Point dot;
void nazatie(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)///MouseDown
{
    Button temp = sender as Button;
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        iMove = true;
        dot = e.Location;
    }
}

void naved(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)///MouseMove
{
    Button temp = sender as Button;
    if (iMove)
    {
        temp = (Button)sender;
        temp.Top += e.Y - dot.Y;
        temp.Left += e.X - dot.X;
    }
}
```

Как перемещение кнопки можно сделать в wpf, используя мышь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В WPF идея такая же: запоминать точку клика и двигать по дельте. Нюанс в том, что контролы имеют абсолютные координаты только внутри `Canvas` (ну или с помощью отступов).

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="MouseMovableControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Canvas>
        <Label x:Name="btn" Content="Movable"
               MouseDown="Btn_OnMouseDown"
               MouseMove="Btn_OnMouseMove"
               MouseUp="Btn_OnMouseUp" />
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MouseMovableControl
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private Point? _movePoint;

        public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();

        private void Btn_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _movePoint = e.GetPosition(btn);
            btn.CaptureMouse();
        }

        private void Btn_OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _movePoint = null;
            btn.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        private void Btn_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_movePoint == null)
                return;
            var p = e.GetPosition(this) - (Vector)_movePoint.Value;
            Canvas.SetLeft(btn, p.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(btn, p.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Конкретно батоны двигать несколько затруднительно, потому что они проглатывают сообщения о кликах мыши.

Comment: Объект просто исчезает на форме и больше не появляется.

Comment: @B_Im Значит, вы что-то не так скопировали. У меня пример с полным кодом, его достаточно скопировать в новый проект.

Comment: Да, действительно что то не так скопировал. Однако как сделать это с кнопкой, сейчас кнопка игнорирует лкм, но перетаскивается с помощью скм и пкм, однако если кнопку переместить и отпустить, а затем снова попытаться на нее нажать то она начинает возвращаться к начальному положению(из которого мы ее брали). Так же это ее странное поведение наблюдается и во время перемещения. Что это может быть?

Comment: @B_Im У кнопки свои особые представления о том, в каком направлении какие события позволять, а какие глотать, преобразуя в события Pressed. Вы можете попробовать подписаться на события Preview* и/или унаследоваться и переопределить обработчики событий. Также можно закрыть кнопку прозрачным оверлеем, не пропускающим события, и двигать за него. Вам вообще зачем конкретно кнопку двигать?